# coefficients of correlation on AMPL

Tags: postgresql, correlation, psql, minimization, ampl

I have a specific question, and I will deeply appreciate any help please.

I am working on a specific project on AMPL (A Mathematical Programming language): 
I need to implement an objective function that minimizes the risk on the cost for a variable, that has a cost as a parameter and correlation coefficients as well.

The risk is estimated using the variance on cost, and I have my correlation matrix data. 
My correlation matrix looks like this:
correlation coefficients (%)
2015
Coal steam turbine  Gas combustion turbine  Wind    Central PV  Hydro non pumped    Nuclear GenIII  Nuclear GenIV   Coal steam turbine CCS
1   0.47    0   0   0   0.12    0.12    1   Coal steam turbine
0.47    1   0   0   0   0.06    0.06    0.47    Gas combustion turbine
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   Wind
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   Central PV
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   Hydro non pumped
0.12    0.06    0   0   0   1   1   0.12    Nuclear GenIII
0.12    0.06    0   0   0   1   1   0.12    Nuclear GenIV
1   0.47    0   0   0   0.12    0.12    1   Coal steam turbine CCS

In my case, the risk on cost that I want to minimize is on fuel prices ( Fuels types are correlated and coefficients of correlation vary yearly, fuel prices depend on the type of the technology, the province, and the year).

I need to find a way to find an efficient way to enter the correlation matrix in a table ( database on psgAdmin (psql) )  and then use appropriate arguments to read them, and implement them on my objective function.

The table that I have so far looks like this:

```
table fuel_prices "inputs/fuel_prices.tab" IN:
[province, fuel, year], fuel_price, cv_fuel_price;
read table fuel_prices;
```

I need to modify it to add correlation coefficients.

```
# Table for the correlation coefficients
# table fuel_prices_corr "inputs/fuel_prices_corr.tab"  and IN:
#  [province, year], fuel, correl_coeff1, correl_coeff2;
# read table fuel_prices_corr;
```

The technologies I am using are extracted from tables as the following:
    table generator_info "inputs/generator_info.tab" IN:
    TECHNOLOGIES <- [technology], technology_id, fuel;
    read table generator_info;

```
table gen_cap_cost "inputs/gen_cap_cost.tab" IN:
[technology, year], overnight_cost_yearly ~ overnight_cost, fixed_o_m_yearly ~    fixed_o_m, variable_o_m_yearly ~ variable_o_m;
read table gen_cap_cost;

table existing_plants "inputs/existing_plants.tab" IN: 
EXISTING_PLANTS <- [project_id, province, technology], 
ep_plant_name ~ plant_name, ep_carma_plant_id ~ carma_plant_id,
ep_capacity_mw ~ capacity_mw, ep_heat_rate ~ heat_rate,   ep_cogen_thermal_demand ~ cogen_thermal_demand_mmbtus_per_mwh,
ep_vintage ~ start_year,  
ep_overnight_cost ~ overnight_cost, ep_connect_cost_per_mw ~ connect_cost_per_mw, ep_fixed_o_m ~ fixed_o_m, ep_variable_o_m ~ variable_o_m,
ep_location_id;
read table existing_plants;


table new_projects "inputs/new_projects.tab" IN: 
PROJECTS <- [project_id, province, technology], location_id,   ep_project_replacement_id,
capacity_limit, capacity_limit_conversion, heat_rate, cogen_thermal_demand, connect_cost_per_mw;
read table new_projects;
```

My objective function looks like this:pid = project specific id , a = province, t = technology , p = PERIODS, the start of an investment period as well as the date when a power plant starts running, h = study hour - unique timepoint considered, and p = investment period.

sum{(pid, a, t, p)in PROJECT} Gen[pid, a,t, p, h] * fuel_cost[pid,a,t,p]))

Does anyone have a hint on that please, or a project that uses MPT, and correlated variables?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a table declaration for reading a two-dimensional parameter `amt` taken from [here](http://ampl.github.io/tables/mysql.html#usage):

```
table dietAmts IN "ODBC" (ConnectionStr) "Amounts":
  [NUTR, FOOD], amt;
```

In your case, you'll have the same set twice in the key section, something like `[ENERGY_SOURCE, ENERGY_SOURCE]`, where `ENERGY_SOURCE` is a set of energy sources such as Coal steam turbine, etc. Since the matrix is symmetric you only need to store half of it.